# Set empty array as default value in array_agg in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW microservice_view AS
  SELECT
    m.id :: BIGINT,
    m.name,
    m.sending_message_rate :: BIGINT,
    m.max_message_size :: BIGINT,
    m.prefetch_count :: BIGINT,
    (SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(DISTINCT node_id), '[]')
     FROM public.microservice_node
     WHERE microservice_id = m.id) AS nodes,

    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT json_build_object('id', transport_id :: INT,
                                                 'is_available', (credentials ->> 'is_available') :: BOOLEAN,
                                                 'username', credentials ->> 'username',
                                                 'password', credentials ->> 'password',
                                                 'default', (default_transport) :: BOOLEAN) :: JSONB
    )
     FROM transport_microservice
     WHERE microservice_id = m.id) AS transports
  FROM public.microservice m
  GROUP BY m.id
  ORDER BY m.id ASC;
```

Sometimes transports is null. How can I set an empty array as a default value for array_agg? This field should be an empty array or array with data. In some cases I use array_length function to filter the data.

Comment: Coalesce it with something, just like you did with `json_agg()`

Comment: @NickBarnes json_agg is returning json and I can't using array_length

Comment: @NickBarnes also when I tried used coalesce I get {} instead of []

Comment: array_remove(query, NULL) also wont working

Comment: @Illoran, but {} is a actually empty array. Try `select array[]::text[];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't mix `array_agg` with JSON (notice double quotes escaping; also I use `select array( .. subquery ..)` trick here to get an array, it's at some extent an equivalent to your `array_agg(..)`):

```
test=# select array(select '{"zz": 1}'::jsonb);
      array
-----------------
 {"{\"zz\": 1}"}
```

-- here you'll get ARRAY of JSONB, while what you really need is single JSONB value with an embedded array inside:

```
test=# select pg_typeof(array(select '{"zz": 1}'::jsonb));
 pg_typeof
-----------
 jsonb[]
(1 row)


test=# select pg_typeof('[{"zz": 1}]'::jsonb);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 jsonb
(1 row)
```

To get single `jsonb` value (with JSON array inside), use `jsonb_agg(..)` function.

To substitute `NULL` value by some default, as usual, you can use standard function `coalesce(..)`:

```
test=# select coalesce(null::jsonb, '[]'::jsonb);
 coalesce
----------
 []
(1 row)
```

Finally, as I see from additional comments, you need to get array length of your `jsonb` -- there are functions `json_array_length(..)` and `jsonb_array_length(..)` designed for this purpose, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html.

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpfully for me. P.S. In PostgreSQL 9.5.7 documentation I found jsonb_agg

Comment: @Illorian you're welcome. Right, `jsonb_agg` exists, my memory failed here a bit -- there is no `row_to_jsonb` but there is `row_to_json` function, but this is another story.